# Saving PHP form with foreach loop to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'm trying to save question options input into a table in database. However, I can only save the last question inputs into db but not the rest before that.

I'm currently using foreach loop to come out with textfield inputs based on the question structure table.

I don't really know how to explain in words, let me show you my codes.
I'm new in this field, hope you guys understand and help me out :)

- foreachtest.php

  ```
  <?php
  $user_name = "root";
  $password = "";
  $database = "leadership_program";
  $server = "localhost";

  $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
  $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question_structure_tb", $db_handle);

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


  mysql_close($db_handle);
  $survey_name = $row['survey_name'];
  $row2 = array_slice($row, 2);



  echo 'Survey Name: '. $survey_name ;

  foreach ($row2 as $v) {
      //echo "$v\n";


      if ($v != NULL) {

          echo '<p>Question:</p>';

          echo '<p>Enter Question: <input type=\"text\" name=\"question\" size=\"200\" maxLength=\"300\" value></p>';


          if ($v === 'radio') {

              echo"<p>Option 1:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionone\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 2:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optiontwo\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 3:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionthree\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 4:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionfour\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 5:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionfive\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 6:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionsix\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 7:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionseven\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"optioneight\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"optionnine\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"optionten\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"optioneleven\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"optiontwelve\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"optionthirteen\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"optionfourteen\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";

          } else if ($v === 'checkbox') {

              echo"<p>Option 1:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionone\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 2:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optiontwo\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 3:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionthree\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 4:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionfour\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 5:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionfive\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 6:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionsix\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 7:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionseven\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 8:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optioneight\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 9:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionnine\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 10:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionten\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 11:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optioneleven\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 12:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optiontwelve\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 13:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionthirteen\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
              echo"<p>Option 14:<input type=\"text\" name=\"optionfourteen\" size=\"40\" maxLength=\"30\"></p>";
          } else {
              echo "<p>this is comment or with comments.therefore no input field</p>"; 

          }
      } else {

      }
      unset($v);
  }
  ?>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Save" name="B1"></p>
  ```
- foreachtest_save.php

  ```
  $user_name = "root";
  $password = "";
  $database = "leadership_program";
  $server = "localhost";

  $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
  $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);


  if ($db_found) {


      $Questions = $_POST['question'];


      $SQL = "INSERT INTO question_table ('question_detail') VALUES ('$Questions')";

      $result = mysql_query($SQL); //execute the above 

      $Option1 = $_POST['optionone'];
      $Option2 = $_POST['optiontwo'];
      $Option3 = $_POST['optionthree'];
      $Option4 = $_POST['optionfour'];
      $Option5 = $_POST['optionfive'];
      $Option6 = $_POST['optionsix'];
      $Option7 = $_POST['optionseven'];
      $Option8 = $_POST['optioneight'];
      $Option9 = $_POST['optionnine'];
      $Option10 = $_POST['optionten'];
      $Option11 = $_POST['optioneleven'];
      $Option12 = $_POST['optiontwelve'];
      $Option13 = $_POST['optionthirteen'];
      $Option14 = $_POST['optionfourteen'];



      $SQL2 = "INSERT INTO option_table " .
        "(option_one,option_two, option_three, option_four,option_five, option_six, option_seven, option_eight, option_nine, option_ten, option_eleven, option_twelve, option_thirteen, option_fourteen)" .
          "VALUES" .
          "('$Option1','$Option2','$Option3','$Option4', '$Option5','$Option6','$Option7','$Option8','$Option9','$Option10','$Option11','$Option12','$Option13','$Option14' )";

      $result2 = mysql_query($SQL2); //execute the above 

      if ($result2) {
          print "Options added to the database";
      } else {
          print "Error: Options not added";
      }
      mysql_close($db_handle);
  } else {

      print "Database NOT Found ";
      mysql_close($db_handle);
  }
  ?>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

From your code I think you will create a set of input tag, using **the same name** for every question, so I think that's the reason you only get. You can try to declare it as array, and then try to loop through when saving to the database.

Answer (score -1):

From your question:''with foreach loop to MYSQL''

Why not doing it in array if you want to use foreach loop

```
<input type="text" name="salaries[]" >
<input type="text" name="salaries[]" >
```

When submitted

Loop your text field like this

```
$salaries=$_POST['salaries'];

foreach ($salaries as $key => $value){
echo $value;
}
```

If you not sure how to insert with form in array , i suggest you to use [prepare statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

```
//$dbc is your database connection
mysqli_autocommit($dbc,false);  
if($stmt=$dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO question_table ('question_detail') VALUES ('?')")){

foreach ($salaries as $key => $value){

    $stmt->bind_param('s',$value);
    $stmt->execute();
    if(!$stmt){//if statement problem , prevent commit
        echo 'insertion failed , roll back all query';
        exit(); 
    }//end of smtp error

}//end of foreach
mysqli_commit($dbc);
```

Comment: I didn't vote this down but this should have been posted as a comment not an answer if you're asking a question.

Comment: It's completely valid though. Array form data is awesome. [] for the win.

Comment: This works terrifically.It does really and I'm so grateful for it, but it works for storing into only one field. However, I have 14 fields from option_one to option_fourteen.How do I put each values of the array into those different fields?I saw something about implode?How do I go about using that here?

Comment: @fie I think i should write like this.Thanks

Comment: @user2189103 I have no idea how your database look like , and normally i will loop like above to build a string of query , then execute it

Comment: Oh, it's alright.I think I have it figured out. Thank you so much for your help! :)